# Table Cell does not take 100% height

Tags: html, css

I have:
http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=8b9rFEijb5

```
<table>
<tr >
    <td> 
        <b> this </b><br/>
        <b>is</b><br/>
        <b>long</b><br/>
         text
    </td>
    <td>
       <table style='height:100%'>
           <tr style='height:100%'><td style='background-color:red;height:100%;width:100%;' > &nbsp;</td></tr>
           <tr style='height:100%'><td style='background-color:green;height:100%;width:100%;'> &nbsp;</td></tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want the table in the right cell to take all available space. I expect that `height:100%` means it take all availabe height from the parent's tag - but that does not seem to be right.

Comment: anyone seeing anything weird on jsfiddle?

Comment: @Akshay: yes, me too. what was that

Comment: I suggest the "togetherjs" bit is not very useful for a link posted on a SO question :)

Comment: @Nadeem i don't know but i am chatting with it on the 'javascript' secsion page

Comment: sorry, I use jsfiddle for the first time. What is wrong?

Comment: @Ferenjito you seeing this http://i60.tinypic.com/53o0u0.jpg

Comment: yes, looks cool, but I did not know it used to look different

Comment: @Ferenjito it's okay on other jsfiddle pages

Answer (score 0):

try this. this is useful when left `td` inner text will be fixed.

```css
table td {
  border: 1px solid Red;
}

.one {
  background-color: red;
}

.two {
  background-color: green;
}

table table {
  height: 73px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <b> this </b>
      <br/>
      <b>is</b>
      <br/>
      <b>long</b>
      <br/>text
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="one">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="two">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```